# Parse list within a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Let me first describe what I have done :

I have a dictionary named **a** where

```
a={"A":[5],"B": ["ABCD"],"C":["HELLO"]}
```

Whenever I run the code below

```
print ['and '.join(key+"="+"'%s'" % a[key][0] for key in a)]
```

It gives me an output

```
["A='5'and C='HELLO'and B='ABCD'"]
```

So far so good. Now suppose I have a dictionary **b** where

```
b={"A":[5,6],"B": ["ABCD"],"C":["Hello"]}
```

After slightly modifying the above code :

```
 print [' and '.join(key+"="+"'%s'" %str(value[0]) for key,value in b.iteritems()  for each in value)]
```

I get

```
["A='5' and A='5' and C='Hello' and B='ABCD'"]
```

But I want :

```
["A='5' or A='5' and C='Hello' and B='ABCD'"]
```

I know I haven't placed the **or** logic but I could not figure out how and where to place it.
Can anyone please help me regarding this problem? 
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[' and '.join([' or '.join([k + "=" + "'%s'"%str(v) for v in b[k]]) for k in b])]
```

Output:

```
["A='5' or A='6' and C='Hello' and B='ABCD'"]
```